# TypeError: o.Subject is not a constructor - Angular 11

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular11, aot

1. I have upgraded my Angular version from **5.2 to 11.2**
2. After BUILD I am getting error:

> TypeError: o.Subject is not a constructor
> 3. In development mode I am not getting any error, if I set `"aot": false` in angular.json file then it's working fine, here are my rxjs packages:

```
"rxjs": "^6.6.7",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
"rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.8",
```

Comment: you can try and use only rxjs package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have upgraded **@angular/cdk** & **@angular/material** with latest version, before that the Subject coming from OLD version of these libraries.

So, upgrade all libraries with Angular version.